# Resposta deletada deve aparecer no Feed principal?

Tags: suporte

Estava olhando o [feed principal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) de perguntas, e me deparei com essa pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aí, tudo bem. O problema é que ao clicar no link com a frase [modificada 2 horas atrás](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13618/quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagem-entre-frameworks-action-based-e-component-based/150692#150692), ele me leva para a pergunta com uma âncora sem utilização.

[Conversando no Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32077799#32077799), fui informando que a pergunta foi deletada, o que também não tenho nada contra.

O problema é aparecer no feed sem ter algo. Se o que foi feito não existe mais, a alteração não deveria sair do feed?

Comment: O site faz cache de quase tudo (no back-end), será que pode ter sido isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não, cache não causaria isso. De qualquer forma já respondi.

Answer (score 5):

Uma resposta foi apagada, não a pergunta, ela claramente está lá. Sempre que uma modificação ocorre gera um *bump* até para alguém poder auditar se o que ocorreu ali está correto. Muitos não poderão ver o que está ali e poderá gerar surpresa, mas alguns poderão ver e decidir se foi correto ou tomar alguma atitude.

Falando em outras palavras, você quer que um `DELETE FROM table` não seja *logado*? É basicamente isso que ocorre. Dá para se questionar se o "alerta" do que foi *logado* é adequado, mas na prática é a forma de fazer as pessoas terem ciência, se deixar para elas olharem *logs* para achar se tem algum problema, não vai funcionar aqui.

Comment: O que quis dizer não é exatamente a deleção. Pense comigo. O alerta está lá pela **edição**, me corrija se eu estiver errado. Se essa edição não existe mais, porque a resposta foi deletada, por que o alerta deveria existir? Sem falar que meu **"toc"** me deixa frustado quando clico em um link com âncora e ela não serve de nada, pelo menos pela maioria dos usuários.

Comment: Ele não está pela edição, ele está pela deleção, por isso eu usei o exemplo do `DELETE` no SQL. O que poderia ser feito é um *bump* aparecer só para quem pode ver a resposta apagada, mas isso eu sei que vai contra a filosofia técnica da SE, não sei se algo poderia ser feito para mudar a experiência.

Comment: Ela está pela deleção? O user54701 que deletou? O que me confundiu foi o link ser o mesmo que uma edição.

Comment: O que está lá: "removida por Wallace Maxters, rray♦ 2 horas atrás". Uma deleção é uma modificação (algum tipo de escrita), mas não uma edição (escrita que altera dados existentes por outros).